# Proof of increasing sequence CDF

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Im looking for some guidance on how to continue with this problem.

$F_X(X)$ is the CDF of a RV $X$. Let {$x_n$} be an increasing sequence of real numbers with $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} x_n = x_0$. Show $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} F_X(x_n) = F_X(x_0) - P_X(X = x_0)$$

I know that
$$F_X(x) = P_X(X <= x)$$
substituting it in above we get:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} P_X(X <= x_n) = P_X(X <= x_0) - P_X(X = x_0)$$
and applying the limit in the prompt:
$$P_X(X <= x_0) = P_X(X <= x_0) - P_X(X = x_0)$$

My guess is that I would now need to show that $P_X(X=x) = 0$ and that would make the equation true?

Comment: This property will be true even if {x0} has a non-zero probability of occurring (try for example to compute both expressions for $X$ a bernoulli(1/2) RV with $x_n =-1/n$ and $x_0=0$).

Comment: I would then suggest to try to use properties that tell you how a probability measure interacts with sigma-algebra operations like unions or intersections. In this case: $\lim_n P(\{X≤x_n\}) = P(\cup_n \{X≤x_n\})$ since the sequence of sets $\{X\leq x_n\}$ is increasing because the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is increasing.

Comment: @NicolasAgote Are there additional assumptions that are needed for this? For example, assuming all $x_n$ are disjoint and then apply countable additivity?

Comment: No additional assumptions needed. A way to prove the property I suggested is by countable additivity, as you say. Since $(x_n)_n$ is increasing, $\{X\leq x_1\}$, $\{x_n< X\leq x_n+1\}$ for $n\geq 1$ are disjoint so $\mathbb{P}(\{X\leq x_1\}) + \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{P}(\{x_n< X\leq x_n+1\})$ is on the one hand equal to $\mathbb{P}(\{X\leq x_n\})$ and on the other hand converges to the series which by countable additivity equals $\mathbb{P}(\cup_n \{X\leq x_n\})$.

Comment: The property that the probability of an increasing sequence of sets converges to their union is sometimes called "continuity of the measure" and using a similar proof can be proved without additional assumptions. 
What would be needed to complete the proof you seek is then to relate $\cup_n \{X\leq x_n\}$ to $\{X\leq x_0\}$.
HINT: $\cup_n \{X\leq x_n\} =\{X<x_0\}$ assuming there is no $x_n$ which equals $x_0$  and if not then it is equal to $\{X\leq x_0\}$ instead. If you can assume $(x_n)_n$ to be strictly increasing then you can guarantee you are always in the first case.

Comment: If the sequence is constantly $x_0$ from some point onwards then the result may be false (once again, compute both expressions for a bernoulli random variable but now with $x_n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_0=0$), so the hypothesis need to be revised in order to guarantee $\cup_¨n \{X_n\leq x_n\} = \{X<x_0\}$ in order for the result to be true.